# node blogs, screencasts, and resources to watch

Tags: node.js

I've been developing a node.js + express.js web app, but the problem I keep running into is project or blog abandonment. I realize node is still relatively new and going through some growing pains perhaps.

What are some node resources that are still active for learning how to build web apps with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these,

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/?search_index=4

http://www.nodebeginner.org/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/16/useful-node-js-tools-tutorials-and-resources/

http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/

http://camp.nodejs.org/videos/

http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/beginning-node-js-express-tutorial

These are my book marks for learning node. They have been helpful. But ofcourse, node changes alot, and by the time you probably read or watch some of these, there has been a new version of node. Be sure to watch the git page node, and pay close attention the the changes.

Comment: i've read most of the tutorials out there. Most of the links you listed are limited to one or two examples. Are there any other regularly updated node related blogs or tutorial sites?

Comment: nettuts is pretty good, i also like dailyjs. They feature pretty good node segments. They are also a pretty good source of everything web. Especially with dailyjs's modules review. And nettuts around the web specials. Is there anything in particular you are building? Maybe I can help narrow your search.

Comment: i'm looking for regular tutorials building a web app with nodejs.

Comment: This is complete self-promotion here, but I recently started a screencast series on Node.  It's at www.learnallthenodes.com.  There are only 2 episodes right now, and they're fairly beginner-oriented.  But there will be a new one each Monday.  Maybe it will be useful to you.